# iOS Provisioning Profile - Cannot install (developer cert trust result = 5)

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

I recently generated a new certificate and provisioning profile and I'm unable to install (install loop) the IPA on a device.

- device is registered in the provisioning profile
- profile is on the device
- profile is valid
- profile is listed un Xcode
- cert is in my keychain, all green

I'm using Hudson to build the IPA and it all worked fine until I had to updated the cert and the profile.

Console log I'm getting when installing:

> Jan 10 12:12:52 Martins-iPhone SpringBoard[1790] : Killing com.wci.turntape for app installation
>
> Jan 10 12:12:52 Martins-iPhone itunesstored[1788] : LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: com.wci.turntape (Placeholder)
>
> Jan 10 12:12:52 Martins-iPhone itunesstored[1788] : LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.wci.turntape (Placeholder) withPhase:1
>
> Jan 10 12:12:52 Martins-iPhone lsd[1787] : LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent  to 1
>
> Jan 10 12:12:52 Martins-iPhone installd[62] : 0x303000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-3941318386609200153/2973774017215790161" requested by itunesstored
>
> Jan 10 12:12:55 Martins-iPhone installd[62] : 0x303000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.wci.turntape
>
> Jan 10 12:12:56 Martins-iPhone installd[62] : developer cert trust result = 5
>
> Jan 10 12:12:56 Martins-iPhone installd[62] : 0x303000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.p38MaR/foo_extracted/Payload/Turntape.app/turntape: 0xe8008018
>
> Jan 10 12:12:56 Martins-iPhone installd[62] : 0x303000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.p38MaR/foo_extracted/Payload/Turntape.app
>
> Jan 10 12:12:56 Martins-iPhone installd[62] : 0x303000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
>
> Jan 10 12:12:56 Martins-iPhone itunesstored[1788] : 0x1e60000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
>
> Jan 10 12:12:56 Martins-iPhone itunesstored[1788] : ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
>
> Jan 10 12:12:56 Martins-iPhone lsd[1787] : LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.wci.turntape

Does anything in the log ring a bell to anyone?
But all my

I found this guy with the same issue 
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/error_on_installation-p3psw
But his solution was to renew his expired certificate (which is what I did in the first place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spilling a lot of blood, I've found what was causing the problem...

The new certificates now have an organizational unit id (mine was YXW8YWB9K4) has a suffix to the certificate. Hudson was configured to look for the certificate without this suffix.

The problem was that we also had an Enterprise certificate and the build was getting messed up between the two certificates. With the previous certificate, there was no ambiguity because there was no suffix.

So I had to add the suffix my build parameter .

Example:
"iPhone Distribution: Company Inc"

And my certificates were:

"iPhone Distribution: Company Inc (YXW8YWB9K4)"
"iPhone Distribution: Company Inc (Ent)"

Btw for those having an Enterprise account, Apple's advice is to have a separate keychain for those certificates.

Comment: I also have a developer and an enterprise program.  My developer program got the suffix when I renewed the certificate.  I ran into this issue because I was trying to resign a .ipa file with my own script that didn't take the suffix into account.  So thanks for posting this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check once again that the IPA you are distributing is being signed with the correct profile. Make sure your new certificates are having the bundle identifier for the matching profile.